# Restoring from Time Machine to different type of Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, imac

I have been using a Time Machine for back ups for about 2 years now. Recently, I got a new iMac 27in and ‘restored’ it from my MacBook Air backup (most updated OS). I chose all the options as seen below: [image: Setup options]

I have noticed that my new iMac is running a bit sluggish, I am attributing this to the fact that it a Fusion Drive, but I am also being told that it could be because I copied over *all* the files (including Computer & Network Settings)

Is it *advisable* to restore a Mac from a different Macs Time Machine?

Comment: *How* recently is recently? Don't forget macOS can spend literally days indexing, performing photo library curation and other background tasks which will slow everything down. Give everything at least a week, perhaps two if you had a lot of data to transfer.

Comment: I mean the restoration from Time Machine took like 2.5 hours (which is fine, I don’t care about that). But I have been using the computer for about a week now normal use (since the restoration).

Comment: After getting used to an SSD, any spinny rust drive is going to feel very slow.

Answer (score 2):

Actually that is, in most cases just fine.

I've been restoring my user profile on an older Mac to a newer Mac since the Migration Assistant was available on OSX. And I always do what you just did, restore *everything.*

That said, if you were having issues with your networking on the old Mac then it *might* carry over to the new Mac. But I have never seen restoring the network settings to a new Mac cause the new Mac to misbehave in any way.

That said, just because I didn't have any problems doesn't mean it can't happen. You could go through your `~/library/Preferences` and `/Library/Preferences` folders, delete any networking related files and reboot. That would likely tell you if that was the problem.

Comment: Cool! I haven’t been having any issues _specific_ to networking, but this is good to know! Just more a sluggish computer and thought it may be attributed to this.

Answer (score 1):

The Fusion Drive is significantly slower than the SSD on a MacBook Air. There is a portion of SSD on the Fusion Drive, but after copying all of your files over from your old Mac, it will take the operating system quite a while to determine which are the files/programs you use the most in order to "optimize" (i.e. put on the SSD portion of the Fusion Drive).

After you've been using the computer regularly for a week or two, it should speed up a little (assuming you are consistently using the same software). But it will never be as fast as a pure SSD like on your MacBook Air.

Comment: In my case I ended up just opening this one up and throwing in an SSD, but this should be good news to others. Cheers

Comment: Great idea, Matt. Cheers.